# foo e bar - Tem algum significado especial?

Tags: terminologia

Na maioria dos exemplos de códigos em várias linguagens, eu vejo essas duas nomeações para variáveis - `foo` e `bar`. Existe algum significado especial para elas?

Comment: Eu ficava muito confusa com esse foo quando procurava exemplos de implementações em documentações até descobrir que o foo nada mais é do que uma palavra aleatória que serve para demonstrar que vc pode personalizar o exemplo demonstrado de acordo com o uso que vc necessita...pode trocar por outro nome qualquer que vc deseja e encaixar o trecho em seu próprio código.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

A origem do termo `foo` é obscura. A conexão com `bar` é normalmente tida como um termo usado por tropas americanas na segunda guerra mundial, vindo da sigla FUBAR que significa "*Fucked Up Beyond All Repair*" -  Que traduzindo para o português é a expressão (perdoe-me o palavrão) "*Fodido além de todo o [possível] conserto*" - Ou seja, quebrado/zoado de uma forma irrecuperável. Entretanto, essa origem, apesar de plausível, é tida como incerta.

A origem de "*foo*" isoladamente é um pouco mais antiga, mas pode ser atribuída aos quadrinhos [Smokey Stover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smokey_Stover) que começaram a ser publicados em 1935, quadrinho no qual a palavra "foo" era muito importante. Os quadrinhos eram recheados de itens absurdos, veículos bizarros, muitas peças e coisas esquisitas cujo funcionamento parecia ser improvável ou impossível, e muitas vezes simplesmente davam errado. Muitas dessas coisas tinham a sílaba *foo* no nome. Também havia vários diálogos sem sentido. Enfim, havia muita gambiarra lá!

Segundo os criadores de *Smokey Stover*, a palavra *foo* vem do chinês e significa "boa sorte". Em chinês, 福 (que pode ser transliterado como *fu* ou *foo*) significa felicidade. *Foo* também pode ter origem no francês *feu* (que significa "fogo"), sendo que o protagonista do *Smokey Stover* era um bombeiro que se dizia ser um *foo fighter* ao invés de um *firefighter* ("bombeiro" em inglês).

Em programação, os termos `foo` e `bar` começaram a aparecer por volta dos anos 1960, e também têm origem obscura, embora tenham aparecido juntos. A primeira aparição confirmada foi em 1965, embora eles possam ser um pouco mais antigos. Costumavam aparecer em códigos bastante gambiarrados, ou em coisas que eram reutilizadas um grande número de vezes em contextos e situações tão diferentes, que fica até difícil dar nome ou se definir a finalidade de tal coisa. Isso claramente remete ao que acontece no *Smokey Stover* e na sigla FUBAR - Uma coisa super confusa, bizarra e estranha que está tão zoada que não pode mais ser consertada.

Em resumo, *foo* e *bar* são apenas nomes genéricos para gambiarras.

Informação obtida em sua maioria na wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: Quando meu inglês era mais que básico eu achava que significada "bar cheio".

Answer (score 17):

Sobre os populares `foo` e `bar`, são termos em inglês bastante usados na programação para ilustrar exemplos (nome de variáveis, métodos, funções, classes...). Apenas isto. Não há significação especial. Trazendo para o português (mutatis mutandis), é como se fosse `fulano` ou `sicrano` da linguagem de programação, ou o `x` e `y` da matemática.

### Origem

Há bastante teorias sobre a origem destes termos. Referências:

[Wikipedia - foobar (PT-BR)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar).

[RFC3092 - Etymology of "Foo" (EN)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3092.txt)

### Algumas definições (do inglês)

**Foo**

> An term used for unimportant variables in programming when the
>   programmer is too lazy to think of an actual name.

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=foo

> Used very generally as a sample name for absolutely anything, esp.
>         programs and files (esp. scratch files).

https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3092.txt

**Foobar**

> A common term found in unix/linux/bsd program help pages as space
>   fillers for a word.  Or, can be used as a less intense or childish
>   form of fubar. To run the program, simply cd to the directory you
>   installed it in like this:  user@localhost cd foo/bar

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=foobar

Comment: patrão legal a atenção... mai num põe em inglês não... o link até vai, mas não a definição...tenta traduzir...

Comment: Citação (no quadro amarelo) é ipsis litteris, ou seja, nos mesmos termos. A minha resposta está no primeiro parágrafo. São termos em inglês, afinal. Mas editei para indicar em que língua está a referência.

Comment: Desculpe a curiosidade, onde posso encontrar essa informação, sobre o quadro amarelo ser "ipsis litteris", ou você está dizendo que nesse caso específico é isto, não estou lhe questionando, só quero entender melhor o sistema do site...

Comment: O quadro amarelo - pelo menos aqui no SO - é uma citação (block quote), ou seja, por definição, uma maneira de trazer para o texto uma menção a uma informação externa, com preservação do texto original e citando a fonte. Como uma transcrição.  Achei este guia [aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas/1297#1297). Procurei dar a resposta (pelo menos minha opinião) em português e depois citar as fontes originais (na falta de encontrar material em PT-BR). Mas traduções em PT-BR são sempre bem vindas, você está certo. Abraços

Comment: Vlw por ter respondido...suave hehe... é que comecei a ler tava em portuga, quando comecei me interessar virou gringo ... sua resposta tá da hora... Mas na minha opinião ia fica melhor se o inglês tivesse traduzido...
Inda mais pq são as partes mais legais da história... Esse foo bar inda vai longe... eu queria saber também, tipo embora eles não tenham um significado e tals...eu li alguma coisa num me lembro onde, que eles tem umas ligação entre si... que faz uma analogia com a programação e funções da matemática...vou procurar.. Vlw man num leva a mal naum...